# angular 2 inline if/esle with click

Tags: angular, angular-template

simply I want to run a function on click only when certain condition exists , I don't need to add extra function in component ts file to check for the condition , I need to do it inline, like

```
 <button (click)="'condition==true'?runFunction()">
```

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sajeetharan noted, its best to do the check inside your controller. If its not suitable for you, you could also have 2 buttons in your template, like this:

```
<button *ngIf="condition" (click)="runFunction()">
<button *ngIf="!condition">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating the function inside the component.ts

```
check(){
  if(condition){
     callThatFunction();
  }
}
```

and in **`HTML`**

```
<button (click)="check()">
```

Comment: it is a very simple condition, just checking for a flag, I don't want to make my component complicated just to check for a flag

Comment: haha! why do you think it makes your component complicated? its the same thing